# STS 3.7.1 - Error: Could not find or load main class 64bit.STS

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Yesterday I downloaded last STS 3.7.1 64bit and I have problem with Maven in it.
Run as > maven install > Error: Could not find or load main class 64bit.STS

OS: Win7 64bit

Hope it's clear enough, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have any steps to reproduce this issue, starting from a plain STS install? If this erorr persists, you could also open a ticket at our issue tracker for STS: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS

Comment: Hello Martin. Yes, it is plain STS install. I am not able to opening new ticket because I have not jira account at issuetracker.springsource.com.

Comment: you can create a new account there. Having an issue for this would be helpful, especially with a few steps how to reproduce it, starting from a plain STS install. Since I've installed and used STS in Win 64bit without those issues, it looks like we need more details and some steps to reproduce this issue.

Comment: looks like you got the issue filed: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4245

Comment: Move STS to "D:/" (path without spaces) and maven works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract sts zip folder the same folder with eclipse.